# How to change look and feel of a scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am developing web applications using Ext JS 4.x framework and working with data manipulation using JSON. For displaying data I'm using `GridPanel`. The interesting point here is that Grid panel scollbar stays natively, it's look and feel won't get changed!!

But it's documentation uses wondereful small compact scrollbars, FB also uses this styling.
I am asking then how to change `GridPanel`'s scrollbar style to what the docs API web page has it!

I'd like it to look like the following pic [image]

How to change it's style using CSS?

Comment: Probably you need to create your own scrollbar like example: [Custom scrollbar](http://livepipe.net/control/scrollbar) Other examples: [Another custom scrollbar](http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar)

Comment: Nice resource! How about it's cross browser compatibility?